# Meaning of “No simplicity of mind, no obscurity of station, can escape the universal duty of questioning all that we believe”

Tags: meaning

> No simplicity of mind, no obscurity of station, can escape the universal duty of questioning all that we believe

How do understand this sentence?

Comment: It is a very complicated way of saying: **Everybody has the duty to question the basis of what they believe, regardless of how uninformed they are or what position / rank they may occupy.**

Answer (score 1):

It means, *It doesn't matter how weak your intellect is, or how low your position in life, you cannot avoid the duty of questioning all that we believe*.

In this very literary style, *no (quality) ... can (do something)* means *however great (the quality), one cannot (do the thing)*.

*Obscurity of station* is also very literary, or very old-fashioned. *Station* means "rank or position in society", and *obscure* (which normally means "hidden") here means refers to "so low a rank that you are not seen".